# jQuery script won't run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function that basically toggles a div on click but it doesn't work I can't tell if I maybe imported the library incorrectly or what but I can't get it to function at all. Please tell me if I am missing anything or messed up my code somewhere.

My exact code looks like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.notifications-dropdown-trigger").click(function () {
      $('#post-notifications-dropdown').toggle('slide', {
         duration: 100,
         direction: 'up'
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

The HTML markup:

```
<a class="notifications-dropdown-trigger">click me</a>

<div id="post-notifications-dropdown">
 .... code
</div>
```

Everything is coded directly onto servers and is live the moment I save.

Comment: Can we see your HTML markup?

Comment: any errors on console..?

Comment: I think you want `direction: 'toggle'` but I could be wrong, hence why I'm not adding an answer.

Comment: oh yeah, lemme add the html,sec

Comment: I actually think just `.toggle('slide', 100);`would do the trick

Comment: Also, don't forget to `preventDefault()` the event!

Comment: I added the html but its just a `<a>` tag with a word which is the trigger and a hidden `<div>`, pretty straight forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**.slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

*Code*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.notifications-dropdown-trigger").click(function (event) {
      $('#post-notifications-dropdown').slideToggle(100);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Comment: The script isn't running. I've tried things out on fiddle and it works perfectly, but its not working on my actual page so I keep thinking that its related to how I'm importing jQuery or how my <script> tags are set up since fiddle doesn't include those. Otherwise its copied and pasted from a working fiddle.

Comment: @user3767853, How are you loading file? Like `file://.......` if thats the case the use `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com....` use `http://` protocol

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: which file? the jQuery? or the actual page

Comment: Its being coded directly onto development servers so its live the moment I save